# Efficient implementation of List but every operation is reversed

Tags: python, list

I'm seaching for an efficient python module/class that flips every list operation.

Implementation should be efficient. I, too, can write a class that proxies every operation with `list(reversed(lst))`

---

For example assume `class flipped_list(list): ...` exists.

```py
>>> lst1 = [1,2,3,4]
>>> lst2 = flipped_list(lst1)
>>> print(lst2)
[4, 3, 2, 1] 

>>> lst2.append(5)  # This is the important part!!!
>>> lst2
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1] 
>>> lst2[0]
5
>>> lst2[-1]
1

>>> lst2.extend(["a", "b"])
>>> lst2
["b", "a", 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

I'm looking for much more functionality than this. For example `extend`, `slice`, `reverse`, ...

I couldn't find anything but maybe someone implemented this. I know it's wired but I have an use case.

Comment: What's wrong with `collections.deque`? It allows for efficient operations on either end of a list-like data structure, e.g., replace `append` with `appendleft` and `extend` with `extendleft`.

Comment: The fact that me not knowing about it makes it really hard for me to consider `deque` as an option. Thanks! It's what I'm seaching for.